# jQuery UI problem centering a dialog

Tags: jquery-ui

I've got a jQuery dialog box that does display and respond to button clicks correctly.  Unfortunately it's always positioned at 0, 0 in the browser window despite my attempts to convince it otherwise.  Any ideas?

```
    var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
  .html('my message')
        .dialog({ autoOpen: false, title: 'my title', position: 'center', bgiframe: true
        });

    $dialog.dialog('option', 'buttons', buttons);
    $dialog.dialog('option', 'position', "center");
    $dialog.dialog("open");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it isn't automatically centering, then you have an error in your document markup (a missing closing tag is typically the culprit).

http://jsbin.com/uhago4/edit

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.
I did not know how to take my jquery dialog box to center.
 
I have tried in so many way.
 
Nothing worked for me.

But finally I found the solution, my solution is

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Comment: To Anyone using DNN and getting an uncentered modal: I had this problem while using DotNetNuke (which uses jQuery UI). This was exactly the problem, the skin that I had deployed needed the accompanying [template].doctype.xml file with the doctype declaration which was not being deployed with my skin. Once I deployed the doctype declaration the modal started centering again.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery uses the width of the dialog to center it.  If it has not been displayed yet, appended to the DOM, or created with a fixed width, then it has no width and can't be centered properly.

To fix, just center after opening:

```
var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
.html('my message')
.dialog({ autoOpen: false, title: 'my title', position: 'center', bgiframe: true
  });

$dialog.dialog('option', 'buttons', buttons);
$dialog.dialog("open");
$dialog.dialog('option', 'position', "center");
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing `position: 'center'` worked for me. Ironic right?